# Is there any "Telerik to Crystal" report converter?

Tags: crystal-reports, telerik, report, converters

Stackoverflowers!

I have a set of reports built on Telerik that I want to convert to Crystal Reports instead.
Is there any way to convert these reports from Telerik to Crystal? All I've found so far is a way to do the opposite: convert from Crystal to Telerik.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your consideration and help!

Answer (score 1):

No such converter is available. As you noticed Telerik provides converters only to their reporting engine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The first question is: Is there any way to convert these reports from Telerik to Crystal? My answer is negative but I think it is still relevant.